AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'self.createTilemap'
This is the error:
File "e:\Pygame\main.py", line 23, in new
    self.createTilemap()
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'createTilemap'

I created a Tilemap on a separate code named config using this program:
import pygame
from sprites import *
from config import *
import sys

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        
        def createTilemap(self):
            for i, row in enumerate(tilemap):
                for j, column in enumerate(row):
                     if column == "B":
                         Block(self, j, i)
                     if column == "P":
                         Player(self, j, i)


    def new(self):
        self.createTilemap()
        # a new game starts
        self.playing = True

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.blocks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.attacks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

        self.createTilemap()`

Everything else works, but the self.createTilemap() line wouldn't run.

Dedent the entire createTilemap method by one level. That'll put it in the same scope as all the other methods instead of within __init__.

you are calling self.createTilemap() and createTilemap function is inside the init function.

The reason is because the createTileMap() function is indented, so it is inside the function __init__() and can only be accessed there. So to fix it just use this code:
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        
    def createTilemap(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(tilemap):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == "B":
                    Block(self, j, i)
                if column == "P":
                    Player(self, j, i)

